# How to display custom token in custom block

Tags: 8, tokens

In a Drupal 8 website I created a custom token that is working in basic page.

Then I created a custom block with a WYSIWYG field :

```
class Myblock extends BlockBase {

  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  public function getMachineName() {
    return 'my_custom_blcok';
  }


  public function label() {
    return $this->t('Block label');
  }

  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    $form['my_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#format' => 'content_manager',
      '#title' => $this->t('Field name'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['my_field']['value']) ? $config['my_field']['value'] : '',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->setConfigurationValue('my_field', $form_state->getValue('my_field'));
  }


  public function build() {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    $content = $config['my_field']['value'];

    return [
        '#theme' => 'simulator_block',
        '#content' => $content,
      ];
  }
}
```

If I type `My content [module:my_token]` in the WYSIWYG.

The following content is display :

```
<p>My content [module:my_token]</p>
```

How can I replace the token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the formatted text in a render element `processed_text`:

```
 $content = [
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $config['my_field']['value'],
    '#format' => 'content_manager',
  ];

  return [
    '#theme' => 'simulator_block',
    '#content' => $content,
  ];
```

Configure the text format to include the token filter.

Comment: It's not working. I think that 'processed_text' is a Drupal 7 type was removed in Drupal 8 ...

Comment: It's in Drupal 8, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21ProcessedText.php/class/ProcessedText/8.6.x. I think when you use an input element for formatted text you should use one for output too. Otherwise this is not safe, because, besides the token filter, dependent on what content you allow in the text format, you might need to apply more filters before you can output the content.

Comment: I missed that what you did was in build() and not in blockForm() so indeed it's working and your solution is better.